# Android - Multiple task execution in parallel

Tags: java, android, parallel-processing, task

Language: Java

I want to execute multiple tasks in parallel.

As soon as application start, 1st task continuously runs in background. This will continue run till app is closed

When user is in input screen and click on particular functionality, 2nd task should start in background until user complete the given process. Few variables from 1st background task also needs to be used in this task.

```
onPreExecute()
doInBackground()
onPostExecute()
```

We have separate class for each task. **2nd** task will be completed when variable set to true in **1st** process. But doInBackground() code block is not at all executed.

Do we need to do something more while starting thread in parallel?

Comment: Have a look at the Single Activity architecture with the NavigationComponent (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate) and a shared ViewModel, where you can put your `AsyncTask` that runs in the background. If you need to wait for the first task to complete before the second task can run, why not just put them in the same task instead multiple tasks? You'd make things a lot easier for yourself if you used Kotlin and Coroutines where you can make asynchronous work wait for each other quite easily.

Comment: Hello Darwind, Thanks for your reply. No. 1st task will always keep running and 2nd task will take state of 1st task and then execute accordingly after completion

Answer (score 0):

What You Are Looking For Is A two Separate Threads Sending Messages To Each Other
I Suggest using Handler Thread [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread) , handler And Message

Example

```
public class BackgroundThread extends HandlerThread {
    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundThread";
    private Handler handler;

    public BackgroundThread() {
        super("BackgroundThread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLooperPrepared() {
        super.onLooperPrepared();
         handler = new Handler(getLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            
        }
    };
        Log.d(TAG, "onLooperPrepared: ");
    }

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }
}
```

I Suggest This [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDl4WUKi26WbzLMsM1sXCD4) On YouTube is explaining that very nice